# How do i use Href but not get redirected? using HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

SO basically I want to send a value using Href from Maintenance.html to another page called delete.php
so I am fetching the values from the table and sending it to Delete.php using  `$("#tddd").append("<td><a href='delete.php?grievance_number="+field.grievance_number+"'>Delete</a></td>");`

This is my table in maintenance.HTML page

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


         $.getJSON("http://192.169.245.144/grievance_app/v1/view/default", function(result){
             $.each(result, function(i, field){
               $("#tddd").append("<tr>");
                 $("#tddd").append("<td>"+field.grievance_number+ "</td>");
                 $("#tddd").append("<td>"+field.customer_name+"</td>");
                  $("#tddd").append("<td>"+field.subject+ "</td>");

                   $("#tddd").append("<td>"+field.description+"</td>");
                   $("#tddd").append("<td>"+field.email+"</td>");
                   $("#tddd").append("<td>"+field.phone_number+ "</td>");
                    <!--$("#tddd").append("<td>"+field.status+ "</td>");
                // $("#tddd").append("<td>"+field.number + "</td>");
                 $("#tddd").append("<td><a href='delete.php?grievance_number="+field.grievance_number+"'>Delete</a></td>");
                 $("#tddd").append("</tr>");
                    console.log(field.grievance_number);
            });
                console.log(result);
         });


});

</script>
```

and this is my delete.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['grievance_number'])) {




    $service_url= "http://192.169.245.144/grievance_app/v1/update/default";

    $curl = curl_init($service_url);

    $grievance_number = $_GET['grievance_number'];



    $curl_post_data = array(
    "grievance_number" => $grievance_number,
    "status" => "Closed"

    );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($curl_post_data));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    echo "this is the $grievance_number";
    if ($response === false) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));

}
curl_close($curl);

$decoded = json_decode($response);
if (isset($decoded->response->status) && $decoded->response->status == 'ERROR') {
    die('error occured: ' . $decoded->response->errormessage);

    }
echo 'response ok!';


    }

    ?>
```

instead of redirecting the page I would just want it to send the data using `href` and refresh the current HTML page instead, or a popup saying success, don't want to redirect. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: use ajax if you dont want to redirect and also delete something

Comment: post your html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ajax to send data to the server without page refresh.
You can do something like this

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "delete.php?grievance_number="+field.grievance_number+"",
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(data) {
        show_items();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`href` is meant to take you to the new page

If you want to delete anything and you don't want to move to any other page, you need to use `Ajax`. Learn about `Ajax` and you will be good to go.